# Regex only if group sequence not followed by?

Tags: swift

Using Swift 4.2, trying to match a regex similar to 1980 / 1989 / 2019 etc., but what I need is a match only if sequence is not followed by "p" ? what I'm trying ... "(?:[1-2]{1}[0,9]{1}[0-9]{1,2})\1(?![p])"

Comment: Assuming Swift regex supports it, your negative lookahead at the end looks correct.  What is wrong with your current pattern?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word)

Comment: Returns nothing.

Comment: Is this about regular expressions or swift? Depending on which it is could you clarify your question with some sample data (and code if relevant) and given result vs expected result

Answer (score 0):

After plenty of testing I found a solution ... "(?:([1-2]{1}[0,9]{1}[0-9]{2})(?![p]))"

Comment: This matches `1975`, `2020` `2999`

Comment: ... and `1,80` because of `[0,9]`

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider this string :

```
let str = """
10 Hello 980 world,
1975 Hello 1980 world,
1985p Hello :1995 world,
2000 Hello 2005p world,
2010 Hello 2015 world,
2019 Hello 2020 world,
2999
"""
```

Let's declare this regex :

```
let pattern = "19[89]{1}[0-9]{1}(?![p])|20[01]{1}[0-9]{1}(?![p])"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)
```

Here are the different parts of the pattern :

- `19` matches the characters `19` literally,
- `[89]{1}` matches a single character in the list `89`, to limit the years to the 1980s and 90s,
- `[0-9]{1}` one digit for the year,
- `(?![p])` negative lookahead, meaning: not followed by `p`,
- `|` logical OR,
- `20` matches the characters `20` literally,
- `[01]{1}` matches a single character in the list `01`, to limit the years to the 2000s and 2010s,
- `[0-9]{1}` one digit for the year,
- `(?![p])` negative lookahead, meaning: not followed by `p`.

Now, let's get the matches :

```
let matches =
    regex.matches(in    : str,
                  range : NSRange(location: 0, length: str.utf16.count))

for match in matches {
    let range = match.range
    if let swiftRange = Range(range, in: str) {
        let name = str[swiftRange]
        print(name)
    }
}
```

Which prints in the console :

> ```
> 1980
> 1995
> 2000
> 2010
> 2015
> 2019
> ```

---

<sup>Bear in mind that this would still match things like 1990s, 1999a, 19999999, since you've only asked to not be followed by p.</sup>